# In jQuery how can I show content previously appended without appending again?

Tags: jquery, hover, append, addclass, removeclass

Struggled to adequately describe the scenario in the question. I'm trying to learn jQuery so there will no doubt be a bundle of mistakes in what I already have.

This is the jQuery code I have thus far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function () {
   var path = $(this).attr('rel');
   var text = $(this).attr('title');
   $(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"));
   $('p.revealer').hide().fadeIn(500);
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('p:last').hide();
    $(this).removeClass('x').addClass("revealed");
  }
 );
 $('a.revealed', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function() {
   $(this).find('p').show();
  },
  function() {
   $(this).find('p').hide();
  }
 );
});
```

and the HTML is basically

```
<a class="x" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="image1.jpg" title="Image">
 <img src="icon.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Icon" />
</a>
```

My previous incarnation of this used remove() to remove the p tag on mouseout and worked okay. I wanted to try and change it so that the content was just hidden, and the class changed so that if mousenter occurred again it would just show the existing content. Instead I find that it still appends the content again and stacks up on each enter/out. Can anyone suggest where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this solution which provided the functionality I sought.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
  function () {
  if($(this).hasClass('revealed')){
    $(this).find('p.revealer').fadeIn(500);
  }
  else{
   var path = $(this).attr('rel');
   var text = $(this).find('span.y').html();
   $(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"'/><br />"+text+"</p>"));
   $(this).find('p.revealer').hide().fadeIn(500);
   }
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find('p.revealer').hide();
    $(this).addClass("revealed");
  }
 );
});
```

with this HTML

```
<a class="x" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="image1.jpg">
 <img src="radio-hover.png" width="15" height="15" alt="Image available icon" />
 <span class="y" style="display:none;">Any follow up content required</span>
</a>
```

Originally the title attribute was used to supply the var text but I found I occasionally need to include html in here and so adopted this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should append the element only once, and have the hover show/hide it:

```
 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).each(function() {
     var path = $(this).attr('rel');
     var text = $(this).attr('title');
     $(this).append($("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>").hide())
 });

 $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover(
     function () {
         $('p.revealer').fadeIn(500);
      },
      ...
```

By moving the element insertion to outside the hover, it won't be created over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the .append() myself, and either use a  with the jQuery .html().

```
  $('a.x', $('#innerlayout')).hover( 
  function () { 
   var path = $(this).attr('rel'); 
   var text = $(this).attr('title'); 
   $(this).children("span").html("<p class='revealer'><img src='"+path+"' /><br />"+text+"</p>"); 
   $('p.revealer').hide().fadeIn(500); 
  },  
  function () { 
    $(this).find('p:last').hide(); 
    $(this).removeClass('x').addClass("revealed"); 
  } 
 );
```

Then the HTML something like:

```
<a class="x" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="image1.jpg" title="Image">
 <span></span>
 <img src="icon.jpg" width="40" height="40" alt="Icon" />      
</a>
```

Apologies as I've not tested it, but hopefully something to get you on the right track.
You can then either hide the span, or rewrite the HTML to be blank.